# Upgrading From EF 4x to 6 breaks everything

Tags: entity-framework

Attempted to upgrade my project from EF4 to EF6, I get build errors

It appears that if i swap out the namespaces manually to include the entity.core it works, but if i change the .edmx file at all, the code reverts back to the old references and i have to manually edit the code generation files to include the update namespace references.

I have attempted to "add code generation item" that does not resolve the issue at all. When i open the .edmx file in the IDE it shows me everything correctly.

Comment: The greatest change was from 4 to 5: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj618295.aspx.

Comment: Did you try it [this way](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24697836/1016343)?

Answer (score 0):

1. open the edmx file
2. click in an empty space

3.in property tab, change the code generation strategy in the edmx file to T4.

Also be sure to have added the EF6.x code generation template (.tt file)