# How do I rename entity framework .edmx file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a new MVC 4 project developed by a third party. I want to rename the .edmx file before making some other changes and going to production. I can rename the file itself but the .tt files do not change.

Comment: Delete your tt files and regenerate them, or just simply rename them aswell.

Comment: I did try deleting them thinking they would be generated after a rebuild but the did not. Renaming does not seem to be an option when I right click on the files in solution explorer. I was thinking of  renaming them in Windows Explorer, just doesn't seem that anything is ever that easy.

Comment: When you deleted them you have to open the edmx right click on a free space on click add code generation item. Look here for some more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19496744/upgrade-ef-4-edmx-to-ef-6/19497412#19497412 its basically the same steps.

Comment: That did most of the trick. I also went into the properties of the edmx diagram and changed the Entity Container Name and Namespace to match the new name and did a file search and replace of the entire solution to get all the classes in line. After a rebuild it all seems to work. If you provide an answer, I'll gladly accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I need to rename my edmx, the designer, diagram and both T4 template files. This is what I did -

1. Unload the project in VS, edit, rename all above files to whatever you have to. The first part of the name of all these files should be same.
2. Open project directory in Windows explorer and manually rename all above files. Names should exactly match with what you entered in project file in step 1.
3. Open both tt files, find and replace the original edmx file name there.
4. Open EDMX file in a text editor, find and replace  with
5. Reload the project, right click both the tt files one at a time and Run Custom tool. This will regenerate any missing files.

Comment: This works great, just a couple of pointers: 4.1 You also need to modify your diagram file (.edmx.diagram) and replace there all instances of the original name with the new one / 4.2 Update the model from the database to refresh the connection string in the app.Config file