# How can I permanently fix the "EdmFunctionAttribute is obsolete" warning, which occurs after upgrading to EF6?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework-4, migration, entity-framework-6

I am getting the warning **"EdmFunctionAttribute is obsolete"** after I have [upgraded a **database first project** from EF4 to EF 6.1.3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24697836/1016343):

> 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.EdmFunctionAttribute' is
>   obsolete: 'This attribute has been replaced by
>   System.Data.Entity.DbFunctionAttribute.'  C:\{myProjectPath}\DataContextEntityObjects.cs

The attribute is used in various places like

```
    [EdmFunction("DataContext", "Split")]
    public IQueryable<Split_Result> Split(global::System.String rowData, global::System.String splitOn)
    {
    // ... auto-generated code ...
    }
```

If you fix that in the *.cs-files mentioned by the error message, then each time when the model gets updated via **update the model from database**,
the error comes up again.

How can this issue **permanently** be fixed (so a model update doesn't bring it up again)?

Comment: Do you have the latest version of Entity Framework tools for VS2013?

Comment: @Gert Arnold: I am using version 6.1.3 of EF, published 10th March 2015, with Entity Framework 6 Tools for Visual Studio 2012/13 and EF 6.x EntityObject Generator. During the conversion I have changed the project from EF4's DbContext to EF6's ObjectContext.

Comment: Why `ObjectContext`? That's almost the same as downgrading. I can imagine that they didn't even bother to update the ObjectContext code generation.

Comment: @Gert Arnold: The EF4 project was hard to upgrade, the only way to do it with reasonable effort was to use ObjectContext. So what do you suggest?

Comment: Well, you wrote you went from EF4's DbContext, so the logical step would be to stick with DbContext. Did you mean you started from ObjectContext? If so, maybe you have to modify the t4 template where `EdmFunctionAttribute` is used.

Comment: I tried that, and it worked. Thank you for the hint! I have described what I did in my answer. @Gerd Arnold

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file `DataContextEntityObjects.cs` is auto-generated from `DataContextEntityObjects.tt` and uses the attribute in various places like

```
    [EdmFunction("DataContext", "Split")]
    public IQueryable<Split_Result> Split(global::System.String rowData, global::System.String splitOn)
    {
    // ... auto-generated code ...
    }
```

Since it is **auto-regenerated** each time when the model gets updated via **update the model from database**,
the solution was to modify the T4 template as follows:

I've identified the relevant part in the T4 file starts here (lines 214-283):

```
    ////////
    ////////  Write EntityContainer and ObjectContext Function Import methods.
    ////////
    region.Begin(CodeGenerationTools.GetResourceString("Template_RegionFunctionImports"));
    foreach (EdmFunction edmFunction in container.FunctionImports)
    {

        IEnumerable<FunctionImportParameter> parameters = FunctionImportParameter.Create(edmFunction.Parameters, code, ef);
```

As suggested in the template [How to: Customize Object Layer Code Generation](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=139297) and
[Generating Artifacts by Using Text Templates](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=139298), the template can be modified to generate the right code.

**Do the following:**

1. Open up the `DataContextEntityObjects.tt` file
2. Search and replace the following:

   [image: EdmFunction replacement]
3. Save the file `DataContextEntityObjects.tt`

From now on, each time you update the model, this will generate the corresponding *.cs file, create the attribute inside correctly and hence the obsolete warning goes away.