# Connect Mvc5 project to exist EF4

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an existing EF4 Model with hundreds of tables. 
I want to use it with my new MVC5 project, but I get an error.

Steps I've tried:
1. Remove current EF6 dll and add the EF4 dll
2. Remove the lines in the web.config and add the lines to fit EF4.

the code I added:

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1">
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
  </assemblies>
```

doesn't seem to help:

The error I get:

```
Error   2   Assembly 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' uses 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
```

Any help?

thanks!

Comment: Oh man, no Nuget? See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19496744/upgrade-ef-4-edmx-to-ef-6

Comment: I tried to upgrade my ef4 few times, and didn't succeed to make it work.
I'll try again with the link you shared.
Surely it better.