# Asp Net EF 4 SoftDelete how to exclude deleted lines?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, webforms, soft-delete

I'm using soft deletes by overriding SaveChanges method on the context which works like a charm, but I can't manage to filter the entries that have the IsDeleted column = true.
I'm using EF4, I know it's outdated but the project is large&old and I don't have much experience upgrading EF versions, any recomendation on this is very appreciated too.

I've tried this but it's not working, as soon as I bind my entity to a gridview with a db.Foo.ToList(), I get all the columns, including the softdeleted ones.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>()
             .Map(m => m.Requires("IsDeleted").HasValue(false));
        }
```

Thanks in advance!!

**EDIT**: *I posted the solution I found!!* I hope it works for future visitors. Cheers from Argentina.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at the `NotMapped` attribute data annotation to exclude your `IsDeleted` property.

```
public class Foo
{
    public int ID { set; get; }
    public string Name { set; get; } 
    [NotMapped]
    public bool IsDeleted { set; get; }
}
```

You will need to use `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` namespace to be able to use `NotMapped` attribute.

Alternatively you can try `Ignore()` in your `OnModelCreating` method

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
   modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>().Ignore(t => t.IsDeleted);
   base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

Also check links below on how to upgrade EF

[Upgrade EF 4 EDMX to EF 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19496744/upgrade-ef-4-edmx-to-ef-6)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn469466(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: OP don't want exclude some property. He wants to filter on a specific field for any query to the table

Comment: Exactly, and I managed to get it done, I will update the post soon, though I had to exclude the property from the model directly by deleteing it on the model diagram. Thanks for the links I'm checking those at these moments!

Answer (score 0):

What I did to get this working is:

1- remove the property from the model directly on the graphic view.

2- While on the graphic view of the Model context.edmx, right click on the model you are working on and click on Table Mappings.

3- In there, I seleceted the column IsDeleted, select operator "Is" and on the right side, just enter Null.

After that, all the queries filter the column out and I'm able to list only the rows that are not soft-deleted. 
I saw this solution on one of the 30 posts I read late at night and it works like a charm!